# How to connect android application database to remote server. I have Microsoft assure cloud. how I can connect with it?

Tags: android, remote-server

I  am working on an android application I am new to remote server connectivity. how should I connect my Microsoft assure cloud (SQL) with the android application, and also I wanted to provide authentication.

Comment: it's not a good way to connect Databases. First You should learn about creating Webservice with PHP or Nodjs ... 
than you can use Retrofit or Volly in android

Comment: Write REST services that can be consumed at Android end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.